# Trauert meiner nicht

Tags: pronoun, genitive

I've encountered the following sentence on YouTube:

> Trauert meiner nicht.

[image: Screenshot of a movie scene with the sentence "Trauert meiner nicht." in subtitles]

As far as I know, `trauern` has the form `um jemanden trauern` and in the screenshot there is such a peculiarity: only `meiner` without a preposition.

And what is the type of the pronoun `meiner`?

Comment: Please transcribe the sentence in the image. Visually impaired users will not be able to see your image. That is why all relevant information needs to be in text, so that it is accessible by screenreaders.

Comment: Nevermind, I just did it myself. I keep the comment for a while. Please consider it a friendly reminder for future posts :)

Comment: Also, only transcribed text is searchable, which is also important.

Answer (score 5):

Here, *meiner* is the Genitiv form of the personal pronoun *ich*.

This form is antiquated. It still exists in some dialects, though. For instance in Saxony, I know people who say *wegen meiner* instead of *wegen mir*, or *meinetwegen* ("due to me").

Not just that form of the pronoun is antiquated, but also using *trauern* with the Genitiv (*jemandes trauern*) is outdated, as you already figured out.

Answer (score 1):

"Jemandes trauern" is a quite antiquated way of phrasing that basically isn't used anymore. The meaning is the same as "um jemanden trauern".

"Meiner" is a genitive form of "mein", as for example in

> Das Fell meiner Katze ist weiß.
> The fur of my cat is white.

It can also be read as genetive form of "ich", as in the prayer

> Gott, erbarme Dich meiner.

or

> Sie bat ihn statt meiner. (more contemporary, "statt mir").

I'm not completely sure, but I seem to remember coming across similar phrasings in English: "Don't mourn mine" as a quite outdated version of "Don't mourn for me".

A short search finds basically only one occurence in [an old folk song](https://www.volksliederarchiv.de/sie-fuehren-mich-zur-stadt-hinaus/). In the song, a prisoner who's about to be executed asks his friends(?)

> trauert meiner nit e so sehr

which would be a bit more modern

> trauert meiner nicht so sehr

and in contemporary German

> trauert nicht so sehr um mich

The quote in your screenshot is set in quotation marks, maybe the character in the video is even quoting the song or a similar (very) old source.

As a side note, a similar use of the genetive can for example be found in the bible, in the Book of Genesis (1. Mose 40,14):

> Aber gedenke meiner, wenn dir's wohlgeht, und tu Barmherzigkeit an mir, dass du dem Pharao von mir sagst und mich so aus diesem Hause bringst.

Comment: I think, _meiner_ is not the Genitiv of _mein_ (the possessive pronoun), but the Genitiv of _ich_ (the personal pronoun).

Comment: @JonathanScholbach It can be both, see [Wiktionary on 'ich'](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/ich) and [Wiktionary on 'mein'](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/mein). In this usage, I'd reckon it to be derived from "mein" rather than from "ich", as for example in "trauert nicht um meine Seele", "trauert nicht meiner Seele".

Comment: @JonathanScholbach After some ruminating, deriving "meiner" from "ich" seems plausible enough in this case to add it to the answer.

Comment: I agree, that morphologically it could be both. I tend to think of the personal pronoun because of the syntax: I don't know if a possessive pronoun can stand alone.

Comment: Also, semantics seem to point to the personal pronoun interpretation: It is about mourning about me, not about something I possess.

Comment: One can also say "betrauert mich nicht".